# Continuity of a function at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

A similar has been asked before, but it was confusing. Please help me with it. I need a general method of dealing with such problems

I need to show that the following function is continuous at $0$. $f(0,0)=0$

$$f(x,y)= \frac {x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(y-x)^2}$$

Comment: What's value of $f(0,0)$?

Comment: @Paul oh sorry. $f(0,0)=0$

Comment: This function is not continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Take $x_n=y_y=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $(x_n,y_n)\to(0,0)$, but $f(x_n,y_n)=1\to1\neq0=f(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Let $y=x$. So $\lim_{x,y\to 0}f(x,y)=1\not=0$